# How can I get rid of the extra space on my blog on blogger

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger

I have some extra white space in my layout on my blog which is hosted by blogger. What do I need to do to remove that extra white space? Here is a screen shot of what is happening: https://img.skitch.com/20110211-tbg5tyj5bywyk9isqk29etq66a.jpg

My blog is http://www.gettingmoreawesome.com and you can see it live on there.

Thanks in advance! 
Rishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly try adding overflow:hidden on your .main-inner div:

```
.main-inner {
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```